# $ABC$ is an acute angled triangle, find the perimeter of $DEF$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

Today I've encountered a question like the following;

$ABC$ is an acute angled triangle $m(\widehat{A})=45^\circ$, the feet(?) of the heights from the vertices $A,B,C$ are (in order) $D,E,F$, if the distance between $A$ and the line $EF$ is $6$, what is the perimeter of $DEF$=?

(Note:I am not well familiar with English Geometry terminology, as seen above)

**My Attempts**

Unfortunately I couldn't do so much this time, maybe due to something that I should know to be able to solve the question but don't know,

I have drawn triangle $DEF$...(1)

I have drawn three circles which took $A,B,C$ for centers and were tangent to $|DE|,|ED|,|EF|$....(2) (Thought it might work)

I have realised that I lacked some material about the usage of them...(3)

I have also started with the assumption that $AD \perp EF$ am I right about this?

What are your suggestions to proceed (or to start maybe, a more suitable word)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Delta AEF\sim\Delta ABC$, we obtain $$\frac{AD}{6}=\frac{AB}{AE}=\frac{1}{\cos45^{\circ}}=\sqrt2.$$
Thus, $AD=6\sqrt2$ and 
$$P_{\Delta DEF}=\sum_{cyc}a\cos\alpha=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{2bc}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2abc}\sum_{cyc}a^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)=\frac{1}{2abc}\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)=\frac{8S^2}{abc}=$$
$$=\frac{8\left(\frac{1}{2}bc\cos45^{\circ}\right)^2}{abc}=\frac{bc}{a}=\frac{h_a}{\sin45^{\circ}}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{2}bc\sin45^{\circ}}{\frac{1}{2}ah_a}=\sqrt2AD=12.$$

Comment: I've realised that this problem is way above me(I suppose at least) what is $\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}$ sorry for my ignorance?

Comment: @Deniz Tuna Yalçın $\sum\limits_{cyc}$ it's a cyclic sum. For example for three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have: $\sum\limits_{cyc}a=a+b+c$, $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2b=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a.$